# how to cast doubles from char array

Tags: c#, casting, char, double, byte-shifting

I am shifting in 3 chars from serial port every 3rd char is a double that i split up for the port, so now i need to put it back to gether.

(Value before sending = 0x3F3400 or 0.703125)

```
char[0] = 0x3F  (msb)
char[1] = 0x34
char[2] = 0x00  (lsb)

double total = (char[0] << 16)+(char[1] << 8)+(char[2]); // this part did not work
```

Pls advise how to rebuild this, I dont understand doubles well enough, I cannot even tell which part of a double is the decimal point or - sign
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get yor value, but as help can advice you to use [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx) and byte array like this:

```
var v = new byte[8];
v[7] = 0x3F;
v[6] = 0x34;
v[5] = 0x00;
double total = BitConverter.ToDouble(v, 0);
Console.WriteLine(total.ToString("0.0000000000000"));
```

Comment: close but, idk why values are being thrown off like that, also it seems the double in the microchip is 24-bit, trying now to dig for more details